# Include file from root level in setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools

I'am trying to build a python package using a bamboo pipeline within our working environment.

To trigger the build I have to include a file `build.info.txt` that contains the version number.
This file is at the top level in the repository, thus the repo structure is the following

```
build.info.txt
setup.py
MANIFEST.in
README.md
package/
   __init__.py
   file1.py
   file2.py
```

The file `build.info.txt` has the version number

```
version=x.y.z
```

I would like to use this file to trigger the version number, thus in the `__init__.py` I included a simple parser

```py
from pathlib import Path
path = Path(__file__).absolute().parent / "build.info.txt"
__version__ = open(path).readline()[0].split("=")[-1]
```

This works fine in local mode. However, when I create a package and push it on our pypi server I get the following error at runtime (i.e. `pip install package` works):

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '</PATH/TO/ENVIRONMENT>/python3.8/site-packages/build.info.txt'
```

I changed the behavior of `setup.py` (I use `setuptools`) including:

```py
setup(**other_params, package_data={"": ["../build.info.txt"]}, include_package_data=True)
```

while `MANIFEST.in` looks like

```
include build.info.txt
```

The issue is that `build.info.txt` using `pip install` is located at top level:

```
</PATH/TO/ENVIRONMENT>/python3.8/site-packages/build.info.txt
```

this file is shared among several packages, while I would like to have the file in

```
</PATH/TO/ENVIRONMENT>/python3.8/site-packages/<PACKAGE>/build.info.txt
```

(then I have to manage the parser in `__init__` in order to parse the right file, but this is straightforward)

How can I manage this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to use [*`importlib.metadata`*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html) to read the version of the project.

There was an attempt to formalize and standardize the convention of setting `__version__` in [*PEP 396*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396/), but it never reached full acceptance. And also nowadays this habit goes away, because the need for it isn't that pressing anymore, thanks to `importlib.metadata`. So you could remove `__version__` entirely and 3rd party pieces of code that want to know the version number of your application or library can use `importlib.metadata.version('MyProject')` to read it.

If you insist on having `__version__` in your library, you can turn this around and do the following in your `__init__.py`:

```
__version__ = importlib.metadata.version('MyProject')
```

---

***Asides***:

- If you insist on working with the file `build-info.txt`, then you could symlink it in the package, for example as `package/build-info.txt` (linking to `build-info.txt`), and `__init__.py` could read that file at run-time.

  - Or, as suggested in the comments, symlink `build-info.txt` to `package/build_info.py`, and in `__init__.py`: `from build_info import version as __version__` (this assumes that the content of that file is also valid Python syntax).
- You should not use `__file__` to read package data resources, this is unreliable, use [*`importlib.resources`*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources) instead (it will do this in a much cleaner way, and if needed take care of extracting the files in case the package is zipped, etc.).
- There are tools that can take care of all this version number issues, `setuptools-scm` comes to mind and might fit your needs.

Comment: Another suggestion for the "asides", `package/build-info.txt` could be renamed `package/version.py`, so the line in `__init__.py` becomes as simple as: `from .version import version as __version__`.  And then have `setup.py` automatically generate this file using e.g. scm info.

Comment: To complete my previous comment, see for instance numpy's [setup.py](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/setup.py), esp. the function `write_version_py`

Comment: @demi-lune From what I understood of the question, the name and location of the file is a given. I understood it as it is a convention from their "bamboo" pipeline environment, and it can't be changed. I might be wrong (my answer is also a bit misleading on that, I will fix it). -- But yeah, `./setup.py` could read `./build-info.txt` and generate `./package/version.py`, that could work.

Comment: @sinoroc, you are right: name and the path are fixed.